# Box API User Management tracking_codes Attribute

Tags: box-api

I'm developing some provisioning/de-provisioning scripts for our Enterprise Box account and have noticed that the 2.0 API documentation states that there is an attribute titled "tracking_codes".  I can't seem to see this attribute when retrieving our Enterprise users nor when retrieving a specific user.  Here are the attributes that I am able to retrieve:

```
{
"total_count":1,
"entries":[
    {"type":"user",
    "id":"123456",
    "name":"John Doe",
    "login":"johndoe@null.com",
    "created_at":"2013-03-04T12:09:08-08:00",
    "modified_at":"2013-04-24T08:22:30-07:00",
    "language":"en",
    "space_amount":26843545600,
    "space_used":0,
    "max_upload_size":5368709120,
    "status":"active",
    "job_title":"",
    "phone":"",
    "address":"",
    "avatar_url":"https:\/\/www.box.com\/api\/avatar\/large\/123456"}
],
"limit":100,
"offset":0}
```

Here's what I'm using to get this information:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users?filter_term=johndoe@null.com -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Is there a different API url or url variables I need to use in order to retrieve the "tracking_codes" attribute?  I would like to use this attribute to track the user "type".  We are planning to give more space to different types of users, for instance in our case staff and professors will get more space than students.

Thanks!

Comment: I was able to find the answer. In the documentation for getting Enterprise users (http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-all-the-users-in-an-enterprise) it said "Example Response" which was a little misguiding as I expected the tracking_codes to be in the response.

After re-reading the documentation I see I need to do it this way:

    curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users?filter_term=johndoe@null.com&fields=tracking_codes -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"

Answer (score 0):

You got the answer already.   Use the ?fields parameter to specify the fields that you want.

Basically, we have 2 default JSON return formats.  You can think of them 'mini' and 'most'.  The mini format is used when a sub-object is embedded into a parent.  For example the user JSON is often embedded in things as a XXX_by, such as this one from a file:

```
  "modified_by": {
    "type": "user",
    "id": "17738362",
    "name": "jack florey",
    "login": "jflorey@box.com"
```

As you can see in the [users documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users): we have quite a few fields that are green and therefor do not automatically come out in the 'most' JSON format.  You have to explicitly ask for them with the ?fields query parameter.

BTW, I don't think we've got all the extended fields turned green in our doc, so if you spot one, comment on this discussion, and we'll fix it, and be grateful that you've made the lives of thousands better.